# Linq object Enumeration

Tags: c#, linq

I'm brand new to linq. I'm sure that I'm missing something due to inexperience.

the problem:
I am using linq to query objects and return enumerable Acct objects `where o.Diff!=0`

if I try to enumerate the results I get the error `unable to cast object of type System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair '2[Acct]' to type 'Acct'`.

the question:
how can i return enumerable Acct objects from the Linq query?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class AcctSum
{
  string ID;
  Decimal Amt1;
  Decimal Amt2;
  Decimal Diff;
  ArrayList<AcctDet> lines;
}

public class AcctInfo
{
  Dictionary<string,AcctSum> acct

  //code that adds the data...
  public iEnumerable Discrepancies()
  {
    var results = (from Acct a in acct
                   where a.Diff != 0
                   select a).AsEnumerable<Acct>();
    foreach (var result in results)//at runtime this generates an error

    {
    }                                    
    return results.GetEnumerator();
  }
}
```

Comment: You're interchangingly using Acct and AcctSum. That's doesn't seem right. You can't convert from one to another if Acct is an enum.

Comment: First change the `Acct` in `from` to a variable name not type name, like `variable1`,  then change `AsEnumerable<Acct>()` to `AsEnumerable<AcctSum>()`, and last change the `in acct` to `in acct.Values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, it sounds like you want to be iterating over the values, not the key/value pairs.

That means you *could* use a query like this:

```
var results = from acctSum value in acct.Values
              where acctSum.Diff != 0
              select acctSum;
```

but personally I wouldn't bother using a query expression in this case. I'd just use the extension methods:

```
var results = acct.Values.Where(acctSum => acctSum.Diff != 0);
```

Now, in terms of the return type, I strongly suspect you want to return `IEnumerable<AcctSum>` rather than `IEnumerator` or `IEnumerator<T>`. So you might want:

```
public IEnumerable<AcctSum> Discrepancies()
{
    return acct.Values.Where(acctSum => acctSum.Diff != 0);
}
```

or you might want to "materialize" the query - get *all* the results in one go, and return those (rather than returning a query which can be iterated over lazily). For example:

```
public IEnumerable<AcctSum> Discrepancies()
{
    return acct.Values.Where(acctSum => acctSum.Diff != 0).ToList();
}
```

In particular, by materializing the query you're allowing callers to modify `acct` while they're iterating over these results - if they try to do so while they're iterating over the raw query, they'll get an exception.

You'll also need to change your `AcctSum` class, because `ArrayList` isn't a generic type in .NET. Did you mean to use `List<T>`?

Comment: I will switch the ArrayList to List, I saw it in another sample.  I'm trying this out now, thanks!

Comment: the last example, .ToList(), was exactly what I was looking for;  
The whole thing still feels like a magic trick though.  

I guess it's time to take of the blinders and learn the new paradigm :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that as you iterate over your dictionary, you are casting each item as an Acct, when in fact, each of the items in your Dictionary is a KeyValuePair.  Try something like:

```
from KeyValuePair<string,AcctSum> acctKVP in acct // assuming acct is of type Dictionary<string,AcctSum>
where acctKvp.Value.Diff != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over `acct`, each item is a key/value pair from the dictionary. Assuming the `Acct` object is the value in each pair, you would get all of the nonzero accounts like this:

```
from a in acct.Values
where a.Diff != 0
select a
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's b/c acct is a dictionary (which is an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>, iirc, under the hood.  Change your source from acct to acct.Values

Answer (score 0):

First, the return type should be IEnumerator, not IEnumerable.
Secondly, acct contains a collection of key value pairs, so you have to run the query on the key value (in this case)

```
void Main()
{
    var acctInfo = new AcctInfo();
    acctInfo.Discrepancies();

}
public class AcctSum
{

    string ID;
    Decimal Amt1;
    Decimal Amt2;
    public Decimal Diff;
    ArrayList lines;
}

public class AcctInfo
{
    public IEnumerator Discrepancies()
    {
        var acct = new Dictionary<int, AcctSum>
                       {{1, new AcctSum() {Diff = 0.0M}}, {2, new AcctSum() {Diff = 1.0M}}};

        var results = (from AcctSum a in acct.Values where a.Diff != 0 select a).AsEnumerable();

        foreach (var result in results)//at runtime this generates an error
        {

        }
        return results.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I would return `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IEnumerator`. It's pretty rare to return an iterator from anything other than a GetEnumerator method implementing `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: As would I, but as he was returning the GetEnumerator(), I figured it was deliberate. Either way, something had to change :)

Comment: yup, i messed up.  i was trying to implement so that I could do foreach and/or return it for datagrid binding.  and yes, for binding i needed to adjust the variables to properties :)